# QGIS Union is slow. How to speed up or which alternative to use, creating the same output?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis, dissolve, union

I have two polygon layers which I want to union. One layer (1) is just one big feature, the other (2) contains 250’000+ features. Layer 1 was created this way: Several polygons --> fix geometry --> dissolve. Layer 2 contains the original features but geometry fixed. Both layers are the same CRS, are stored in a separate GPKG and were originally delivered as a ArcGIS GDB (which first I exported to a GPKG).

Now, if I use the QGIS union tool, it takes more than 15 hours to complete (I don’t know how much, but after 15 hours I escaped).

I also tried to split the process by splitting the big polygon to 60 polygons. Then with PyQGIS I created a loop where both layers get filtered (`setSubsetString`: they have a common field-value for overlapping polygons) and then executed the union. This is still very slow – it takes around 2 to 3 hours for one union to complete.

So I tried to union the layers with GRASS `v.overlay` “Operator = or”. This works a lot faster. The problem is that it doesn’t create the same output: If layer 1 overlaps layer 2 the way that layer 2 is on the left AND the right side of the overlapping layer 1, it creates 3 polygons: layer 2 on the left, the overlapping part and layer 2 on the right. I would need it to create just one polygon for the non-overlapping part.

Is there a way to tell the `v.overlay`-tool to create just one polygon per layer, if it gets cut by the other layer?

I also tried to then dissolve the `v.overlay` result. The problem with this solution is, that I would need it to do the dissolve over approx. 10 fields/columns. But in the `v.dissolve` as well as the other dissolve tools I found in QGIS, I couldn’t figure out how to use 10 fields to dissolve a layer.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
Here you can download some [sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q81wownd0xanxn3/sample_geodata.gpkg?dl=0). Layer 1, layer 2 and the solution, how the generated file should look like (solution_after_union).

It is essential that the file in the end still contains all the columns as in the solution file (except “GENRE” and it could also be only one of the two fields “fid_2” and “NOM”).  The most important thing is that the process creates multipart-features.

I try to explain it as follows: The polygons of layer 2 (parcels) should be max. two polygons after the union-process. Which means that if the forest cuts a parcel (see “NUMERO” 626, 628, 629), the result should be one single-part-polygon which contains the part where the forest overlays the parcel and one multipart-polygon which contains both non-forest parts of the parcel. Same thing the other way around: if the forest is on both sides of the parcel (see “NUMERO” 625), the result should be one multipart-polygon, which contains both forest-parts overlaying the parcel, and another singlepart-polygon, which contains the non-forest part of the parcel. Obviously if there are several parts of forest overlaying one parcel the way the non-forest part of the parcel gets split up in several parts as well, the result should be two multipart-polygons.

The purpose of all this:

Farmers in Switzerland have to declare how they plough every single parcel. What they grow: e.g. if they produce wheat, soy, hay, let the animals grass, etc. But also “non-food” things like forest, trees or similar stuff.

The data I use for my union-task is from the Swiss cadastral survey. It says whether the land is grassland/crops or non-productive (which I declared as forest to make it simple).

Now I want to visualize what the farmers declare. If they declare “non-food” I want to join the data of what they grow to the “forest”-part of the parcel. If they declare whatever sort of food-production, I want to join the data of what they grow to the “non-forest”-part of the parcel. They usually declare both on the same parcel. And I need the data to be joined only on the “correct” part of the parcel. This way, I can for example control if they declare the correct area per land use type – and help them declare correctly if not.

The data of what they grow, I get as a excel-table. I create a join-field using the parcel number, forest/non-forest, etc.

Comment: Union is slow. Multipart to singlepart on your dissolved layer and create spatial indexes on all layers. What is the task you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: My task: Layer 1 is forest area. Layer 2 parcels. I want to create a new layer where the parcels are split up by forest-part of the parcel and non-forest part. I also need the Information wether it is the forest or non-forest part.

Multipart to singlepart enhances the speed dramatically but then there’s the same problem that I would need to dissolve the result (which I didn’t find a solution for). I tried creating spatial indexes but this was extremely fast (0.5 sec) and didn’t have an effect.

Comment: Maybe you can Intersect parcel-non forest, then parcel-forest, merge?

Comment: If each of your polygons have a unique value in a field, then you can dissolve on that and the F/NF field.  All the other attributes will be included in the dissolve. layer.  I personally hate multiparts so if needed for analysis I typically copy and paste data into Excel and run a pivot table to group/sum data together.  The Group Stats plugin can be used for some of that if you don't have Excel or Calc.

Comment: @BERA I tried this just now. But it seems to me that this isn’t faster either.

Comment: @johns The problem is that I really need the geometry to work with it afterwards. And I really need it as a multiparty feature. 

If I select one field for the dissolve, in the resulting layer, there’s only this selected field plus the ID. I think I would need to select all the fields I want to keep in the result but then I would need to use the dissolve from QGIS, which is too slow.

Comment: Sorry, the question/your is a bit difficult to understand without any screenshot showing what you have and what you want to achieve. It would be also helpful if you could provide sample data.

Comment: I second Babel on the need for more information.  In its absence I'll suggest a couple of other approaches you might look at when overlays are slow.  First, create spatial indexes if you haven't and have both layers in the same coordinate system.  Prior to an overlay you might run a v.generalize on your layers.  If your attribute tables are large, after making sure you have a unique field to link attributes on you could create a polygon layer with no attributes but the link field and use that in the overlay.  If that works then you could join the attributes back to the result.

Comment: If you could describe your purpose of this it would be easier to understand. Even with the sample data I dont understand why you are doing this

Comment: I just edited my question and added information about the purpose of this.
I already tried to create special indexes and same coordinate system. I didn’t try the v.generalize on my layers. I’m not sure, if I really want to do this, since I’m using the cadastral survey data and don’t want to change it, since this is exactly the data which is used by government. As always when you have a lot of data, it gets a lot more complicated to find errors if you don’t use exactly the same data from the beginning. I will give it a try anyway. Also the option with removing and re-adding fields by joining.

Comment: Check my assumption: "If you tidy up layer" layer1_forest" by removing unacceptable mini-polygon artifacts inside the layer in edit mode or programmatically, you will get the expected speed of the Union geo-tool..."

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko: Thanks for the hint. I didn't even check my data, because I haven't seen it to contain mini-polygon artefacts before. After deleting holes <3m2, the process took only 83% of the time (7:35 instead of 9:04). Does anyone know if ArcGIS' Dissolve tool removes very small polygon artefacts by default?

Comment: You have to analyze your data yourself and probably in both manual and software modes to remove artifacts that may be more than 3 m2...

Comment: I was curious. So I exported the exact two layers to a ArcGIS File GDB, installed ArcGIS Pro and executed a Union. It was done in 1 min and 9 seconds and delivered exactly the output I need. QGIS was not able to calculate it during one night. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I think, I didn't point this out sufficiently: It took ArcGIS Pro 1min and 9sec for the WHOLE dataset, which is 30 times larger than the one I did the speed test on with QGIS. (Results 89'310 features compared to 2'867 in my QGIS-speed test)

Answer (score 1):

You can run `Clip` and `Difference` tools from `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing tools`. The advantage of this tools is that a polygon of the input layer that gets split into several parts will still be one multipart feature as you can see on the screenshot (red arrows, selected one feature "forest inside a parcel" (right) and one "non-forested part of parcel" (bottom).

Run both tools with `Input layer` = `Layer2_parcel` and `Overlay layer` = `Layer1_forest`. Copy / paste one layer to the other if you need all polygons on the same layer.

These tools should run faster (don't forget spatial indices!) because `Union` checks for self-overlapping within the same layer **and** the overlay layer. `Clip` and `Difference` only check for overlapping/disjoint parts between the input and overlay layers.

[image]

Comment: I did a speed test on a bigger part of the dataset than provided in the sample data:

Union as the data is: 9:04
Union when i previously deleted the holes in the forest layer <3m: 7:35
Clip, Difference and Merge (using the deleted holes-layer as well): 6:20. I hoped, there would be a bigger difference.

Still: if I run the Clip, Difference and Merge on the whole dataset, it doesn't complete overnight. Is my dataset just too big for my computer (a normally quite fast notebook)? Would you recommend splitting the data, process it and merge it again? Would this help to speed it up as well?

Answer (score 1):

You could give [geofileops](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io) a try. This is a python library that tries to speed up processing of larger files and it supports performing a [union](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/geofileops.union.html#geofileops.union).

The result for your sample file is the same.

Note: geofileops also has a function [identity](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/geofileops.identity.html#geofileops.identity). ArcGIS has this as well, QGIS does not. This does like 2/3 of the union: for your example the forest parts that don't overlap with farmers parcels are not included/calculated. If I understand your use case correctly you don't need those polygons, so you could save some time by using identity instead of union.

Code sample for union:

```
import logging
from pathlib import Path
import geofileops as gfo

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
input_path = Path("C:/Temp/sample_geodata.gpkg")
output_path = input_path.parent / "sample_geodata_union.gpkg"

gfo.union(
    input1_path=input_path,
    input2_path=input_path,
    output_path=output_path,
    input1_layer="layer1_forest",
    input2_layer="layer2_parcel",
)
```

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of geofileops